# Table with 2 columns and 3 subcolumns

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to create the table as is shown in the following picture. 
Could you please help me?

[image: How Do I create this table?!]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There's a way, best using `booktabs` and a `tabular`. What have you tried so far (please show a MWE).

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption} % Spaces the caption properly

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{tab:example}
  \begin{tabular}{*6c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A}  \\ \cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}
    B3 & B2 & B1           & A3 & A2 & A1           \\
                                                    \\ \cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{NB} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{NA} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suggest you to look up on the [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Professional_tables) when you need some general information. For any particular package you use, always read its documentation on the [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). A very handy general reference is Stefan Kottwitz's [LaTeX Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/latex-cookbook). It's not gratis, however, Packt often make some deals, so keep an eye on their site if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htpb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{B}  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A}  \\ \cline{1-3}\cline{5-7}\\[-1em]
$B_3$  & $B_2$ & $B_1$ &  & $A_3$ & $A_2$ & $A_1$  \\
       &       &       &  &       &       &        \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{NB} &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{NA} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```